# Iterar sobre `$request` en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

En la función:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Recibo esta solicitud:

```
[
   {
      "iduser":"1",
      "quantity":"1",
      "name":"Haircut",
      "category":"Services",
      "price":"20",
      "createdBy":"Romy Rodriguez",
      "createdBusiness":"Elesmod Barber Shop LLC"
   },
   {
      "iduser":"1",
      "quantity":"1",
      "name":"Haircut & Beard",
      "category":"Services",
      "price":"30",
      "createdBy":"Romy Rodriguez",
      "createdBusiness":"Elesmod 
        Barber Shop LLC"
   }
]
```

Intenté iterarlo con un `foreach`:

```
foreach ($request as $key => $item) {
    // ...
}
```

Pero recibo este error:

> Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::$name

Mi objetivo es crear un registro con cada uno de los objetos del array.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas obtener y cuál es el problema?

Comment: intento crear un regitro con cada uno de los objeto .el problema es con el foreach resivo este error "Undefined property: Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\HeaderBag::$name",

Comment: Gracias con por tu ayuda ya no me da el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `$request` típicamente tienes una instancia de la clase [Illuminate\Http\Request](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; // <- Aquí ves a qué clase se refiere el Request que inyectas en la función store().

class AlgunController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

Si quieres iterar sobre un array con los inputs del request, puedes obtener ese array con el método [all()](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_all) de la clase `Request` (a través del trait `InteractsWithInput`). Ej:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $array = $request->all();
    // luego puedes iterar sobre el array
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        // haz algo aquí con los elementos del array
    }
}
```